# Core Data MagicalRecord merging MOCs in threads

Tags: cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord

iam using MagicalRecord (https://github.com/magicalpanda)

this wasnt working (not marging the MOCs)

```
- (void) foo {
    NSBlockOperation * operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSManagedObjectContext * localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

        // parsing and core data operation on localContext here, savin objectIDs

        [localContext MR_saveNestedContexts];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(){

            onParseFinished(parsedItemObjectIDs);

        }];

    }];

    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

had to replace it with this (ALSO APPLIED THE FIX https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/pull/221)

```
- (void) foo {
    __block NSMutableArray * parsedItemsObjectIDs;
    __block Class parsedItemsClass = [NSObject class]; 

    [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

        // parsing and core data operation on localContext here, savin objectIDs
        ...

    } completion:^(void){

        onParseFinished(parsedItemsObjectIDs);

    }];

}
```

**Whats the issue with the first one? why it was not working and the changes were not merged?**

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact on not merging changes is my time is limited. I try to understand and validate all pull requests that come in, and being a one man shop means my time for open source (free, gratis, not-paying) work is more limited these days. However, I believe the fix was incorporated eventually, it just wasn't evident from the commit history.

As for why it didn't work in the first place, my hunch is that the contextForCurrentThread method returned something that wasn't useful. saveInBackground creates a new context every time it's called to give you a fresh work area. This is the main difference I believe.